# Limits involving theta, cos, sin

Tags: calculus, limits, trigonometry

Question:

$$\displaystyle\lim_{\theta \to 0^-} θ^3 \cos\left(\frac 2\theta \right)$$

also

$$\displaystyle\lim_{\theta \to 0^+} θ^3 \cos\left(\frac 2\theta \right)$$

I have no idea where to begin and I cannot use L'hopitals rule because it has not been covered in my class yet. The only place I can think of looking towards are the trig identities which don't seem to help. If you don't want to explain but can link me to something, that would be great as well! Thank you for your time and any help!

Comment: $\left\vert\,\cos\left(\,x\,\right)\,\right\vert \leq 1$.

Comment: Okay, so just so I'm understanding this correctly. Since cos(2/θ)<=1, that makes the problem equate to 
θ^3*(1). After that, you simply substitute the 0 for theta and that is the answer?

Comment: $\displaystyle\lim_{\theta \rightarrow 0} |\theta^3\cos (2/\theta)| \leq \lim_{\theta \rightarrow 0} |\theta^3| = 0 \quad \Longrightarrow \quad \lim_{\theta \rightarrow 0} \theta^3\cos (2/\theta) = 0$

Comment: The limit does not exist since $\cos$ passes periodically through $0$.

Answer (score 0):

$|Cos(\frac{2}{\theta}) | \leq 1$

Then

$|\theta^{3} \cdot Cos(\frac{2}{\theta}) | \leq \theta^{3}$

applying the limit, you have..

$\lim_{\theta \to 0}|\theta^{3} \cdot Cos(\frac{2}{\theta}) | \leq \lim_{\theta \to 0} |\theta^{3}| = 0 $

Therefore

$\lim_{\theta \to 0}|\theta^{3} \cdot Cos(\frac{2}{\theta}) | =0$

Comment: Thank you. I get the process, but not why it works. Could you maybe explain why the statement before "Therefore" is true?

Comment: it works because of the sandwich theorem. .. and also because $-1 \leq cos (x) \leq 1$

Comment: Right! Should probably take a look at my notes before asking simple questions. Thank you very much for the help!